# Delete from database all selected rows except first two

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I need to delete all dates from database except first two selected dates:

```
SELECT DateColumn 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY date(DateColumn) 
ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
```

I want in one query to delete all dates except first two.

Comment: If more than one row of `Table` has a value of `DateColumn` that would include it into the first two `GROUP`ed result rows, more than two rows will be deleted. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete from table where DateColumn not in(
SELECT DateColumn 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY date(DateColumn) 
ORDER BY DateColumn DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM Table
      WHERE DateColumn NOT IN (SELECT DateColumn 
                                 FROM Table 
                             GROUP BY date(DateColumn) 
                             ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
                                LIMIT 2);
```

Comment: What happens if there are duplicate dates?

Comment: Duplicate dates are `GROUP`ed.