# Deleting all rows from database except first two rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a problem while deleting rows ,
I want to keep two rows in database and delete all other rows
i found a query  in this link [for delete row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154604/delete-from-database-all-selected-rows-except-first-two)
but It is gives mysql Syntax limit function.
but in oracle no limit variable available .
how can  i do the same?

```
DELETE FROM Table
  WHERE DateColumn NOT IN (SELECT DateColumn 
                             FROM Table 
                         GROUP BY date(DateColumn) 
                         ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
                            LIMIT 2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cab be achieved through this query

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
 WHERE ROWID NOT IN
    (SELECT ROWIDS FROM (SELECT MIN(ROWID) ROWIDS 
                           FROM TABLE 
                          GROUP BY DATECOLUMN
                          ORDER BY DATECOLUMN DESC)
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 2);
```

The inner most query will return min of rowid's from table and then the immediate outer query will select only two rows to be avoided in the outermost delete.

Comment: This will delete all rows except one, because of the min(rowid)

Comment: @TommyGrovnes Since it is grouped on datecolumn, it will return as many min rowids as the number of groups formed by datecolumn.

Comment: If all your rows have the same date it will leave only one row, since you will only get one group. (Extreme example, but still)

Comment: @TommyGrovnes : I saw your solution. In your first query, the inner query will through error, because you cannot return rowid from group by expression. A independent inner query run will throw not a group by expression error.

Comment: You are right, I fixed it by removing the group by which does not make sense anyways. See my update

Answer (score 3):

Use ROWID, ROWNUM and subquery something like this (not tested)

```
delete from table WHERE rowid NOT IN
    (SELECT rowid FROM (SELECT rowid
                          FROM Table 
                         ORDER BY DateColumn DESC)
     WHERE rownum <= 2);
```

Notice the "double" select is needed because rownum where messes with the **order by** as it is applied after the rownum

If the dates don't matter and you just want to keep two rows (random) it can be simplified to

```
delete from table WHERE rowid NOT IN
    (SELECT rowid FROM table WHERE rownum <= 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Table
  WHERE DateColumn NOT IN (SELECT DateColumn 
                             FROM Table 
                             Where ROWNUM < 3
                             GROUP BY date(DateColumn) 
                             ORDER BY DateColumn DESC
                            );
```

I dont have oracle client to run the query . you can use ROWNUM in Oracle as LIMIT is not available in ORACLE

Comment: This could potentially leave more than 2 rows if the dates are not unique, also the rownum sabotages the order by

Comment: Agree .  If dates or not unique then it can leave more than  2 rows .. but same would be case with LIMIT option .

Comment: you are right about the limit maybe more detail is needed in the question

Comment: why negative Vote ? as far as I know even tommy has agreed that from the details mentioned in question it was the closest answer